# WSDL and SOAP: Return object with methods

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Is there a way to return in soap an object with his methods? If i return xsd:struct in WSDL i only get the properties of the object but i can't use any of the methods.

For example

```
class person
{
  var $name = "My name";
  public function getName()
  {
      return $this->name;
  }
}
```

So after fetching the object:

```
$client = new SoapClient();
$person = $client->getPerson();
echo $person->getName(); // Return "My Name";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with `SOAP`. Basically your PHP class is being mapped to an XML data structure that's defined by an XML schema. This mapping only includes properties and cannot include executable code. `SOAP` is designed for interoperability and naturally you cannot share code between, let's say, PHP and Java or .NET. On the receiving side your XML data structure is being transformed into a data structure of the client's programming language (a PHP class if you use `SoapClient` or a `C#` class if you use `C#`). As the XML data structure only carries property information the executable part of the originating class cannot be rebuilt.

**But** there is one thing that can help if both the SOAP server and the connecting client have access to the same code base (which means the same classes).  You can define a mapping between a `XML` type and a `PHP` class in the `SoapClient`'s constructor using the `classmap`-option. This allows `SoapClient` to map incoming XML data structures to real PHP classes - given the fact that both the server and the client have access to the relevant class definition. This allows you to use methods on the receiving side of the `SOAP` communication.

```
class book {
    public $a = "a";
    public $b = "c";
    public function getName() {
        return $this->a.' '.$this->b;
    }
}

$options = array(
    'classmap' => array('book' => 'book')
);
$client = new SoapClient('path/to/wsdl', $options);
$book    = $client->test();
echo $book->getName();
```

The `WSDL` might look like (copied from one of the `SoapClient` tests and adpated):

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.nothing.com" targetNamespace="http://schemas.nothing.com">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.nothing.com">
            <xsd:complexType name="book">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:all>
            </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <message name="testRequest">
    </message>
    <message name="testResponse">
        <part name="res" type="tns:book"/>
  </message>
    <portType name="testPortType">
        <operation name="test">
            <input message="tns:testRequest"/>
            <output message="tns:testResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="testBinding" type="tns:testPortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="test">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost:81/test/interface.php?class=test/dotest" style="rpc"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://schemas.nothing.com"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://schemas.nothing.com"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="test">
        <port name="testPort" binding="tns:testBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:81/test/interface.php?class=test"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

[The State of SOAP in PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/Wombert/the-state-of-soap-in-php-2528650) might be interesting if you're doing `SOAP` in PHP.

Comment: Oh thank you. Your sollution is good but does not fit my needs. I need the methods to be hidden from the public. Thanks

Comment: You want to use methods on the client side but want to keep them hidden? I don't think that doesn't work at all...

Comment: If i use setClass in the SoapServer i can use hidden methods :) Anyway i can do a workaround by returning a client soap object.